# Libcurl-devel on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, curl

I am trying to build an application that depends on [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) version 7.21 or newer on Mac OS X 10.5.8. I tried downloading and installing the latest version from libcurl's website, but the application I am building still says it cannot find "libcurl-devel".

A devel package is mentioned on libcurl's [download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#MacOSX), but those links do not work, and are only version 7.15 anyways. Is there anywhere I could find a recent version of libcurl-devel for mac, and, if not, how could I build one myself?